# Problem with WICD (as a network manager) and Steam

Tags: networking, kubuntu, network-manager, steam, wicd

So, I like to use wicd as my network manager, as it makes some of my games much nicer to play on. Sadly, for some reason, when I moved to Kubuntu, Steam seems to fail when I use wicd, but doesn't when I use the standard NetworkManager. Since I really don't have any idea what would cause it, I wanted to see if anyone knew what was going on.

My system uses the following kernel:

> uname: Linux hyperbeam 4.8.0-27-generic #29-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 20 21:03:13 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0):

In case you also get "Fatal Error: Steam needs to be online to update. Please confirm your network connection and try again" installing `libnss-resolve:i386` seems to fix the issue.
https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/4661